# Possible reasons for redirection to /dev/null suddenly breaking

Tags: bash, io-redirection, devices

I am using a Bash loop to monitor a process that I spawned, and after some time (hours/days) it sometimes produces an "operation not permitted" error trying to redirect output to /dev/null:

```
/script.sh: line 4: /dev/null: Operation not permitted
```

The script looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
command &
pid=$!
while kill -0 "${pid}" &>/dev/null; do
  sleep 1 # cannot use `wait "${pid}"` for reasons
done
```

Now, I wonder what could result in /dev/null becoming.. Well what exactly? Inaccessible? Corrupted somehow?
Could the character special file /dev/null become temporarily unavailable or busy?
When is the "operation not permitted" error used exactly?

Note: I cannot tell if the error persists once it first occurs because the script uses `set -e`. This might be something that I will change, but I am not looking to discuss the pros and cons of `set -e` here. ;-)

Comment: Using `set -e` would not cause the script to exit in this case.  However, the `while` loop would obviously end.  Could you try redirecting the loop rather than each individual `kill`?  `while kill ...; do ...; done >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Thanks @they! Yes, `set -e` will "only" break `while` in this case, but that is already bad enough.. Reg. redirection of the entire loop, that had not occurred to me so far, I will give that a shot. Though I fear that whatever caused the operation not permitted error while opening /dev/null repeatedly _may_ also affect an already opened file!? Let's see..

Comment: Let me rephrase that: `set -e` has nothing whatsoever to do with the loop terminating. It's the redirection failing that causes the `kill` to fail, which causes the loop to terminate. Why the redirection fails is a bit of a mystery to me though.

Comment: Maybe something changes permissions in the background (more or less regularly). What is the output of `stat /dev/null`?

Comment: The fun thing is that the error message is "Operation not permitted", which is `EPERM`, at least on Linux. `EACCES` would be "Permission denied", and that's the one you'd get if it was the file mode bits that disallowed the open.

Comment: @ilkkachu, do you happen to know under what circumstances `EPERM` is used?

Comment: @emike, like this in `chmod()`: "EPERM  The effective UID does not match the owner of the file, and the process is not privileged". Stuff where you need to be root (i.e. have a particular capability), or the file owner. The man page for `open()` seems to have these: "EPERM  The O_NOATIME flag was specified, but the effective user ID of the caller did not match the owner of the file and the caller was not privileged.; EPERM  The operation was prevented by a file seal; see fcntl(2).". Not sure if there's an exact definition for EPERM vs. EACCES.